# Aplicativo en JSF 1.1 se daño despues de actualizar Websphere 8.5 a Websphere 9.5

Tags: java, jsp, eclipse, jsf, websphere

Estoy en un proyecto de migracion de un aplicativo antiguo y cuando actualice el websphere y  actualice las referencias del runtime, todas las acciones que se hacen para llamar a los managed bean no funciona ya que cuando depuro el aplicativo y presiono un boton, la pagina se actualiza, tambien probe insertando un breakpoint en el metodo que se esta llamando y no se detiene la ejecucion para analizar el codigo.

Lo unico que noto extraño es cuando configuro los facets, aparecen mas en la version que tiene el runtime del websphere 8.5 que la version 9.5:

RAD con Websphere  8.5:
[image: RAD con Websphere 8.5]

RAD con websphere 9.5:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

durante la migración del WebSphere 8.5 a la versión 9.5, que pudo haber ocasionado el fallo de porque los Managed bean dejaron de responder?

Gracias.

Comment: Nos cuentas una historia, más no haces ninguna pregunta.

Comment: Esta bien, la pregunta puede ser: durante la migración del WebSphere 8.5 a la versión 9.5, que pudo haber ocasionado el fallo de porque los Managed bean dejaron de responder?

Comment: En los casos donde la tecnología es muy antigua, lo recomendable es que empaquetes tu aplicativo con las librerías de JSF o las incluyas con share libraries, porque podría que las librerías de la nueva version de WebSphere te estén causando el problema.

Answer (score 0):

el fallo era que esa versión de JSF no es compatible con WebSphere 9.5, por lo que ese aplicativo se mantiene en la versión de WebSphere 8.5. gracias por la ayuda a todos.